# Nautilus Connect to Server using open ssh

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, nautilus

I have to connect to a server using "Connect to Server" option in 
**Ubuntu 14.04**. 
I had a .ppk key file (Putty) which i exported to openssh using PuttyGen.
How do I connect to the server and where do I add my key?
I tried adding the key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` but first there was no file/folder with the name authorized keys in the directory, secondly I could not open the open ssh key file as it required a password to open.

Kindly help me connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Default place where your ssh keys are stored is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for RSA key. But you can store the key in other places and say `ssh`, where it is using `~/.ssh/config`, for example:

```
Host my-remote.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_remote_rsa
```

The default files should certainly work and it should be picked up and used.

Comment: I do not have the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file. 
the output of `ls ~/.ssh/` gives the output as :
`known_hosts`